# Ubuntu 16.04 "Cheese" HD Video Recording Choppy

Tags: 16.04, video, webcam

When I record videos using "Cheese" the picture keeps freezing while I am recording a video for a fraction of a second.  It has the effect of making my lips and audio seem out of sync.  (Example: frame 22 being displayed instead of different pictures on frames 23 through 30, yet the audio is consistent with what was recorded)

I had this issue before.  Updating the video editing software "Kdenlive runtime environment" resolved this.  Then it started again about 6 weeks ago immediately after I ran updates.  Running updates during the past 6 weeks hasn't resolved it.

I don't want to paste extraneous information here.  If you will tell me what details I need to provide in order to find a solution I will gladly do so.

I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Are the results any better using guvcview?